# Replicate pandas ngroup behaviour in polars

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I am currently trying to replicate [`ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) behaviour in [`polars`](https://www.pola.rs/) to get consecutive group indexes (the dataframe will be grouped over two columns). For the R crowd, this would be achieved in the dplyr world with [`dplyr::group_indices`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_data.html?q=group_indices#ref-usage) or the newer [`dplyr::cur_group_id`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html?q=cur_group_id#ref-usage).

As shown in the repro, I've tried couple avenues without much succcess, both approaches miss group sequentiality and merely return row counts by group.

Quick repro:

```py
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"],
        "cat": [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    }
)

df_pl = pl.from_pandas(df)

print(df.groupby(["id", "cat"]).ngroup())
# This is the desired behaviour
# 0    0
# 1    0
# 2    1
# 3    1
# 4    2
# 5    2
# 6    3
# 7    3
print(df_pl.select(pl.count().over(["id", "cat"])))
# This is only counting observation by group
# ┌───────┐
# │ count │
# │ ---   │
# │ u32   │
# ╞═══════╡
# │ 2     │
# │ 2     │
# │ 2     │
# │ 2     │
# │ 2     │
# │ 2     │
# │ 2     │
# │ 2     │
# └───────┘
# shape: (4, 3)
print(df_pl.groupby(["id", "cat"]).agg([pl.count().alias("test")]))
# shape: (4, 3)
# ┌─────┬─────┬──────┐
# │ id  ┆ cat ┆ test │
# │ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
# │ str ┆ i64 ┆ u32  │
# ╞═════╪═════╪══════╡
# │ a   ┆ 1   ┆ 2    │
# │ a   ┆ 2   ┆ 2    │
# │ b   ┆ 1   ┆ 2    │
# │ b   ┆ 2   ┆ 2    │
# └─────┴─────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

As @jqurious points out we can use `rank` for this:

```py
(df.with_row_count("idx")
 .select(
     pl.first("idx").over(["id", "cat"]).rank("dense") - 1)
)
```

```
shape: (8, 1)
┌─────┐
│ idx │
│ --- │
│ u32 │
╞═════╡
│ 0   │
│ 0   │
│ 1   │
│ 1   │
│ 2   │
│ 2   │
│ 3   │
│ 3   │
└─────┘
```

Comment: Could `.rank()` also be used here? `df.with_row_count("idx").select(pl.first("idx").over(["id", "cat"]).rank("dense") - 1)`

Comment: I believe rank("dense") would also take care of groups that appear again later in the sequence

Answer (score 1):

The following might be more clear:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"],
        "cat": [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    }
)

(
    # Add row count to each line to create an index.
    df.with_row_count("idx")
    # Group on id and cat column. 
    .groupby(
        ["id", "cat"],
        maintain_order=True,
    )
    .agg(
        # Create a list of all index positions per group.
        pl.col("idx")
    )
    # Add a new row count for each group.
    .with_row_count("ngroup")
    # Expand idx list column to separate rows.
    .explode("idx")
    # Reorder columns.
    .select(["idx", "ngroup", "id", "cat"])
    # Optionally sort by original order.
    .sort("idx")
)
```

```
┌─────┬────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ idx ┆ ngroup ┆ id  ┆ cat │
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ u32 ┆ u32    ┆ str ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0      ┆ a   ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 0      ┆ a   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 1      ┆ a   ┆ 2   │
│ 3   ┆ 1      ┆ a   ┆ 2   │
│ 4   ┆ 2      ┆ b   ┆ 1   │
│ 5   ┆ 2      ┆ b   ┆ 1   │
│ 6   ┆ 3      ┆ b   ┆ 2   │
│ 7   ┆ 3      ┆ b   ┆ 2   │
└─────┴────────┴─────┴─────┘
```